# Rails & FreeagentCentral API Usage

Tags: ruby-on-rails, api, web-applications, rest

I have a rails application that uses the FreeagentCentral API to create new projects in FreeagentCentral when a new case is created in my application.

Once the case has been created, I link to the created project in FreeagentCentral using the following link code:

```
<%= link_to "#{image_tag('/images/icons/freeagent.png')} Freeagent Project",   "#{Freeagent::Base.site}#{Freeagent::Project.element_path(@kase.freeagent_id).gsub!(/.xml/,'')}" if @kase.freeagent_id %>
```

What I would like to do, is show a list of invoices that have been created in FreeagentCentral under the project - in my application. So for example, if I create a case in my app it would then be created as a project in FreeagentCentral. If I then created 3 invoices in FreeagentCentral within that project, the 3 invoices would be listed within the case show view of my app.

I am using a FreeagentCentral API gem made by Aaron Russell:

```
http://github.com/aaronrussell/freeagent_api
```

I have done what I understand to be necessary, which is added the following to my `kases_controller.rb` file under the show section:

```
def show
@kase = Kase.find(params[:id])
@invoice = Invoice.find(params[:freeagent_id])
```

I don't know if that's correct, or if it should in fact be:

```
def show
@kase = Kase.find(params[:id])
@kase = Invoice.find(params[:freeagent_id])
```

Also, once the above is correct - how do I list any invoices found within that project in my show view?

```
<% for invoice in @kases %>
    <li><%= link_to ??, kase %></li>
 <% end %>
```

If it helps, this is the code I use from `kase.rb` to send the case to FreeagentCentral as a project:

```
    # FreeAgent API Project Create
    # Required attribues
    #   :contact_id
    #   :name
    #   :billing_basis                    # must be 1, 7, 7.5, or 8
    #   :budget_units                     # must be Hours, Days, or Monetary
    #   :status                           # must be Active or Completed
   def create_freeagent_project(current_user)
    contact = Freeagent::Contact.find_by_name(company.companyname)
    p = Freeagent::Project.create(
      :contact_id             => contact.id,
      :name                   => "#{jobno} - #{highrisesubject}",
      :billing_basis          => 1,
      :budget_units           => 'Hours',
      :status                 => 'Active'
    )
   user = Freeagent::User.find_by_email(current_user.email)
    Freeagent::Timeslip.create(
      :project_id => p.id,
      :user_id => user.id,
      :hours => 1,
      :new_task => 'Setup',
      :dated_on => Time.now
    )
    Freeagent::Task.create(:project_id => p.id, :name => 'Telephone Discussions')
    Freeagent::Task.create(:project_id => p.id, :name => 'Investigation')
    Freeagent::Task.create(:project_id => p.id, :name => 'Travel')
    Freeagent::Task.create(:project_id => p.id, :name => 'Survey')
    Freeagent::Task.create(:project_id => p.id, :name => 'Correspondence')
    Freeagent::Task.create(:project_id => p.id, :name => 'Report')
    Freeagent::Task.create(:project_id => p.id, :name => 'Claim Assessment')
    self.freeagent_id = p.id
    self.save
  end
```

Any help anyone could shed on this would be gratefully received!

Thanks,

Danny

Answer (score 0):

Try that:

```
@kase = Kase.includes(Invoice).where('Kases.id = ?, Invoices.id = ?', params[:id], params[:freeagent_id])

<% for @kase.invoices.each do |i| %>

<% end %>
```